# Authenticate Google App users with Google OAuth2 API

Tags: java, rest, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-apps

I'm wondering if I can use the google client api (java) to authenticate the users of a google apps domain to my application.
The target application is a web application using a REST backend (jersey).

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2) isn't very clear (or I misunderstood it), and the samples in the documentation refers to deprecated classes... Does someone knows if it's possible and the best way to do it.

A code sample would be appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Apps accounts should work fine with the APIs.

The only exception to this is if the service is disabled by the domain administrator. For example, if the Google+ feature is disabled by the domain administrator, you're not going to be able to access that user's Google+ data.

No code change is necessary, so you should be able to use the code from any of the [samples in the client library repository](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/?repo=samples) or the product specific samples like [this one for Google+](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/source/browse/).

The Google+ starter project implements the OAuth flow first by extending `AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet` in `com.google.api.sample.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeServlet`

```
public class OAuth2AuthorizationCodeServlet 
    extends AbstractAuthorizationCodeServlet {
    /**
     * If the user already has a valid credential held in the 
     * AuthorizationCodeFlow they are simply returned to the home page.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("/");
    }

    /**
     * Returns the URI to redirect to with the authentication result.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest request)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        return ConfigHelper.REDIRECT_URI;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the HTTP session id as the identifier for the current user.  
     * The users credentials are stored against this ID.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getUserId(HttpServletRequest request)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        return request.getSession(true).getId();
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() throws ServletException,
                    IOException {
        return Util.getFlow();
    }
}
```

And then by completing the flow in `com.google.api.sample.Oauth2CallbackServlet` by extending `AbstractAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet`:

```
public class OAuth2CallbackServlet 
    extends AbstractAuthorizationCodeCallbackServlet {    
    @Override
    protected void onSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, Credential credential)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("/");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, 
            AuthorizationCodeResponseUrl errorResponse)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.sendError(SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Something went wrong :(");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest request) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        return ConfigHelper.REDIRECT_URI;
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationCodeFlow initializeFlow() 
            throws IOException {
        return Util.getFlow();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getUserId(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException {
        return  request.getSession(true).getId(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: How about the timeout, will this automatically be handle in this class, or do I need to perform additional handling in case it get invalid?

Comment: The client library does indeed automatically (and transparently) handle token refreshes. You don't need to worry about timeouts or other cases that may cause a token to become invalid.

Comment: Google's OAuth Servlet code can be found here: https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client/tree/dev/google-oauth-client-servlet