# How to implement Google OAuth for an app to be deployed on google cloud?

Tags: java, rest, angular, oauth-2.0, gcloud

I'm trying to implement Google OAuth in my rest services (built on jersey, using maven to configure dependencies).

I looked for resources online but none of them gave me a clear picture. 
Moreover, I read up on *google-oauth-java-client*, but how to implement in my rest services.  I'm using Angular2 as front-end technology.

Please help me find a path through this.

Comment: May be this one helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684292/authenticate-google-app-users-with-google-oauth2-api?rq=1

Comment: Maybe you need to use GAE endpoint feature to achieve what you want.

Comment: Isnt that fr standard environment.. m using Flex Environment